# Main interface can not be changed to my own storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm happy to know that zero code is needed to create interface for iOS app using storyboard somehow, but failed to show my own storyboard by changing 'main interface' of project setting in XCode.

[image: project setting]

Launching app brought me to a black screen which is expected to be a tableview within a navigation.

Having set Colorboard.storyboard as interface should add a grey arrow line pointing to navigation controller in the storyboard....however there wasn't such line.

[image]

Xcode I am using is 6.3...I am wondering if there is something I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see you didn't set the initial view controller for storyboard.

In Attributes inspector select the param called "Is Initial Controller"

[image]

More details in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/SetInitialController.html).

Comment: Yes it works...thx....shame that the tutorial book doesn't mention this....

Comment: @AlanHoo the thing is that by default in the project you have Main.storyboard and it has initial controller by default. But, when you create a new one, it doesn't have controllers at the beginning. So, you need explicitly set initial VC.